# Boundedness of functions satisfying some conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an unbounded interval. Assume $\forall a \in I\exists M(a)>0,\, M(a)<\infty$. Can I deduce that $\sup\limits_{a\in I}M(a)<\infty$ as well? Is there any counterexample for unbounded interval case? I know that for bounded interval, I can use compactness argument but I am not sure about unbounded interval case. Here $M$ is just a constant which depends on $a$.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: "Here $M$ is just a constant which depends on $a$" - isn't in fact a function from $I$ to $(0,\infty)$? Seems like a somewhat strange way to express it. Also, I don't see how compactness of $I$ changes anything unless you assume continuity of $M$.

Comment: Actually it is a part of a proof I am working on. I need the boundedness of $M$ but it looks like this is a fiasco so I will not pursue this idea for the proof.

Thank you for your correction

Answer (score 1):

Take $I=(0, \infty)$ and $M(a)=a$ for a counterexample. The claim is  false even for bounded intervals: take $I=(0,1)$ and $M(a)=\frac 1 a$.

Comment: The best positive result of this type says that if $M$ is continuous on a finite closed interval $I$ then its supremum is finite.

Comment: thanks, I am trying to extend some results from bounded to unbounded interval and I need to remove compactness argument but it seems it does not work